# BigQuery PHP API send json that isn't in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I want to update an existing table I have in BigQuery with a single new row.

I found an example how this could be done if I have that json in a file in Google Cloud Storage:

```
$confLoad->setSourceUris(array(
    "gs://json_file_bucket/some_name.json"
));
$conf = new \Google_JobConfiguration;
$conf->setLoad($confLoad);
$job->setConfiguration($conf);
$service = new \Google_BigQueryService($this->client);
$running = $service->jobs->insert($this->projectId, $job);
```

But I don't understand how this can be achieved without an external json file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're adding just a single row, your best option is to use the `TableData.insertAll()` method, which lets you import a single row or a few rows at a time. More information is [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery).

Here is the code in python (I realize you're using PHP, but it should be somewhat similar):

```
body = {"rows":[
    {"json": {"column_name":7.7,}}
    ]}
response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(
    projectId=PROJECT_ID,
    datasetId=DATASET_ID,
    tableId=TABLE_ID,
    body=body).execute()
```

The alternative is to use 'media upload'. This is as simple as adding a media_body parameter to the job configuration, where media_body contains the data you are loading (and you don't need to specify `sourceUris`. For example:

```
job = {
    'configuration': {
      'load': load_config # specify destination table here
    }
  }
result = jobs.insert(
  projectId=project_id,
  body=job,
  media_body=media_body).execute()
```

There is more information about the media upload option in PHP [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/media_upload).

Comment: The second method would mean that you have to keep 1GB of media_body in the memory, as you need to prebuilt. Is that something you are aware? Or how does this works?